# Can't install LocalDB on Windows 8.1

Tags: sql-server, installation, windows-8.1, compatibility, localdb

I've developed an application that uses SQL Server (in particular LocalDB), and, I have just pushed it out to the client.

The client runs Windows 8.1 x64, but, when I try to install either x86 or x64 version of SQL LocalDB direct from Microsoft, I keep getting this error:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB
>
> Installation of this product failed because it is not supported on this operating system. For information on supported configurations, see the product documentation.

I'm a little bit stuck here, and, quite confused as I am using LocalDB on my Windows 8.1 dev machine.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Which version of SQL? 2012 or 2014? Which edition of Windows 8.1? Plain, Pro, Enterprise?

Comment: LocalDB from Sql 2014 (as in question) - as for Windows, got the same issue on both standard and pro... haven't tested on enteprise but I believe ti applies to all.

Comment: Do you have both 3.5 and 4.0 framework installed? Is Windows Installer updated to the latest version?

Comment: @jlee-tessik - Yep, both 3.5 and 4 installers just say that .net framework is already a part of the OS and don't let me install. Windows Installer - not sure, will check.

Comment: @Wil I believe Windows Installer 5.0 comes with Windows 8.1. Anyway, can you install all pending essential updates and try again? Then all optional updates and try again? This worked for me, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Please right click the LocalDB setup file and check if it is configured with other compatibility mode. And make sure that you choose “Run as Administrator” to start the installation. There is also a similar thread for your reference, which may require you to reinstall  the Windows to resolve the OS error.

[SQL Server 2014 Express why not support Windows 8.1 Pro](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ebee0170-a0d5-4581-8661-e53b3c4bcfb1/sql-server-2014-express-why-not-support-windows-81-pro-?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

Comment: There is no run as administrator option and compatibility mode isn't enabled :(